# Journal folder in azcopy for linux

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm trying to upload files to Azure blob storage using `azcopy` on Debian Jessie and I want to do that in a parallel manner (many `azcopy` instances in the same time). Currently it's failing with

> An error occurred while reading the restart journal from
>   "/root/Microsoft/Azure/AzCopy". Detailed error: The process cannot
>   access the file '/root/Microsoft/Azure/AzCopy/AzCopyCheckpoint.jnl'
>   because it is being used by another process.

According to the docs there's supposed to be `/Z:[journal-file-folder]` flag to specify different journal path, but that doesn't work on Linux, fails with

> The syntax of the command is incorrect. Unrecognized command or
>   argument

I've tried all the variations I could think of, but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux), please use `--resume` option to specify a custom location for the journal file.

> If you want to specify a custom location for the journal file:

```
azcopy \
    --source /mnt/myfiles \
    --destination https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer \
    --dest-key key \
    --resume "/mnt/myjournal"
```